# TimeSeries Forecasting Weka - Java API

Tags: java, time-series, weka, webmethods

I am trying to implement TimeSeries Forecasting in a JavaService in webMethods. My Code is not working and i am completely lost so i would be glad if you could help me! FYI: I used [this](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka) Tutorial.

This is the Exception i get: *com.wm.lang.flow.FlowException: weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser.getSymbolFactory()Ljava_cup/runtime/SymbolFactory;*

I just post the part which is not webMethods specific (normal Java):

In the first part i am building an ARFF File which works fine. Because i saved the file and opened it with the weka Explorer and everything looks fine.

The ARFF file looks like this:

```
@relation Rel

@attribute Count numeric

@data
2758
2797
2861
575
505
4029
```

(just with some more values (59 in total))
I want to forecast the next 3 values.

Forecasting Part:

```
// At the berginning i create and save the arff file, so i have an Instances 
object called 'dataset'

WekaForecaster forecaster = new WekaForecaster();
try {
     forecaster.setFieldsToForecast("Count");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

forecaster.setBaseForecaster(new GaussianProcesses());
forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setTimeStampField("Date");
forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setMinLag(1);
forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setMaxLag(12);
forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setAddMonthOfYear(true);
forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setAddQuarterOfYear(true);

 PrintStream stream = null;
List<List<NumericPrediction>> forecast = null;

try {            
      stream = new PrintStream("./path/forecast.txt");
      forecaster.buildForecaster(dataset, stream);
      forecaster.primeForecaster(dataset);
      forecast = forecaster.forecast(3, dataset, stream);        
 } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
}

// output the predictions
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      List<NumericPrediction> predsAtStep = forecast.get(i);
       NumericPrediction predForTarget = predsAtStep.get(0);
       stream.print("" + predForTarget.predicted() + " ");
       stream.println();
}
```

The Java Code is hard to debug in webMethods, but it seems that *forecaster.buildForecaster(dataset, stream);* is causing the Exception.

What am i missing?

Comment: I rebuilt the program with normal Java in Eclipse and used System.out.prinln instead of writing to a File via a PrintStream. When the webMethods Service crashes it seems, this this is the point where the Java program is printing out a warning in red which might cause the Exception. But i have no clue how to solve this.